# How to search for multiple keywords using snscrape?

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, tweets

is there a way to search multi-words with snscrape? i tried put OR but didnt works

```
# Creating list to append tweet data to
keywords = "'Slots',' Gambling'"
maxTweets = 200
tweets_list2 = []

# Using TwitterSearchScraper to scrape data and append tweets to list
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(keywords).get_items()):
    if i>maxTweets:
        break
    tweets_list2.append([tweet.date,tweet.id,tweet.content,tweet.user.username,tweet.likeCount,tweet.user.displayname,tweet.lang])
    
# Creating a dataframe from the tweets list above
tweets_df3 = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list2, columns=['Datetime', 'Tweet Id', 'Text', 'Username', 'Like Count', 'Display Name', 'Language'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can just add as many search terms as you'd like, according to the thread [here.](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/442)

Though, having read that [sntwitter uses the Twitter advanced search functionality](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape), you can try to use that to your advantage, and use the same pattern in your search query.

So in your case, it would be [(slots OR gambling)](https://twitter.com/search?f=top&q=(slots%20OR%20gambling)&src=typed_query) as a string as your keywords, and not the list.